# Passing command-line arguments on clickonce deployment

Tags: deployment, clickonce, command-line-arguments

Im using visual studio 2005 with C# to develop an application that can either perform certain actions by itself or open a form were the user can choose what to do.  In order to decide which is done, the application checks its arguments [from main(string[] args)].  What I can't figure out or find is, is it posible to create two icons when the application is deployed so that one of them would open the application with no parameters and the other would open it with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you launch the application using an http url then you can pass arguments.  However, you do not seem to be able pass parameters from icons on the start menu or desktop.  The only way would be to have a http shortcut icon that would launch a browser that would then trigger the download of the deployment manifest.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply.  I had found some info that led me to beleive it couldn't be done with regular icons but I just wanted to make sure.